# Selecting items according to tags table with synonymous rows

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, tagging

I have three tables: articles, tags and articles_tags(junction).

inside `tags` I have 3 (relevant) columns:
`id`, `name`, and `alias`.
The `alias` column contains the ID of an earlier *synonymous* tag, if exists (`NULL` otherwise). **There are no loops or chains: all synonymous tags contain the same alias.** E.g.:

### `tags`

```
id    |    name    |    alias
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
8     |   pencil   |    NULL
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
3072  |   pencils  |      8
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
3073  | blue pencil|      8
------------------------------------
```

*(The tags **MUST** have this feature because they are user-typed.)*

Now, let's say I want to perform a search for all articles containing the tags `pencils` or `cats`. I would like them to include *ALL* other synonymous tags (*pencil*, *blue pencil*, *tomcat*, *kitten* etc.).

The query I came up with is as following:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE id IN
    (SELECT article_id FROM `articles_tags` WHERE id IN
         (SELECT id FROM `tags` WHERE COALESCE(alias, id) IN
            (SELECT id FROM `tags` WHERE name IN
                ("pencils", "cats")
        )
    )
)
```

I believe it is working, but I think there might a better way then using 4 subqueries with *IN*s (performance is key, because this will be a common search to perform).

I would very much appreciate a guidance towards a better solution.

Thanks.

### Bonus Question

What if I need to find articles that contain no other tags than the ones searched for?

That is, Selecting all articles that have only the tags "cats" and "dogs" will return articles whose only tags are either ("cats"), ("dogs"), or ("cats", "dogs").

*EDIT:* table structures:

```
id    |    name    |    alias
------------------------------------
...
------------------------------------
8     |   pencil   |    NULL
------------------------------------
...
------------------------------------
3072  |   pencils  |      8 (pencil)
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
3073  | blue pencil|      8 (pencil)
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
6088  |    cats    |     NULL
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
7098  |    dogs    |     NULL
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
7099  |  kittens   |     6088 (cats)
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
7102  |  chiwawa   |     7098 (dogs)
------------------------------------
```

### articles

```
id    |        title       |    content
----------------------------------------
...
----------------------------------------
1     |   I love writing   |    ...
----------------------------------------
...
----------------------------------------
42    |Tips for pet owners |    ...
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
108   |  Drawing my dog    |    ...
----------------------------------------
```

### articles_tags

```
id    |      article_id      |    tag_id
------------------------------------
...
------------------------------------
19    |   1(I love writing)  |    3072 (pencils)
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
21    |   1(I love writing)  |    3010 (poetry)
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
22    |   1(I love writing)  |    123  (books)
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
34    | 42(Tips for pet ...) |    6088 (cats)
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
35    | 42(Tips for pet ...) |    7098 (dogs)
------------------------------------
...
------------------------------------
78    | 108(Drawing my dog) |     7098 (dogs)
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
78    | 108(Drawing my dog) |     8    (pencil)
------------------------------------
```

**desired output:**

Searching for `chiwawa`, `cats` should yield "Tips for pet owners", "Drawing my dog".
Searching for `pencil`, `dogs` should yield "I love writing", "Drawing my dog".

And for the second (bonus) part:
Searching for `chiwawa`, `kittens` should yield **ONLY** "Tips for pet owners", and **NOT** "Drawing my dog" because it also has a `pencils` tag.

*sorry for the amount of text.*

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've essentially got two issues here... the first being relational division - selecting tags that apply to a parent record, which in itself can be a bit of fun.  Here's two relevant links:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/ (Celko)

The answer in this question provides roughly a dozen different ways to query this (and performance benchmarks using PostgreSQL).  Quite informative:

[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

As for "pencil vs. pencils" type tags, I'd suggest handling this via application on input.  Create a "filter" of sorts that maps tags to other inherent tags.  So, when someone enters a "pencils" tag, it automatically either a) filters that to "pencil", or b) enters both pencils and pencil.  This is especially helpful for something like "blue pencil".  Given the relative complexity of the relational division problem as stated above, I think you'll find yourself with a much easier to manage data model if "blue pencil" added both "pencil" and "blue pencil" (and perhaps "blue") tags into the database.

There's a certain point where logic should become part of the application domain and stay out of the database.  This is a good case of such, I believe.  Else you risk trying to force a database engine into something it wasn't really designed to do, and that's no fun at all.

Comment: Thank you. I've started reading the articles you linked here - it's going to take a while..
I'm afraid your suggestion will not work because the situation I'm dealing with is a bit different from what I explained in the question: The tags may have to be written in different forms (for this changes their essence) but still must have (or be) a parent tag, which is a standardized value for interacting with third-party apps.
I'm storing all tags but I also make sure that their aliases are in place (mostly through scheduled queries).

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the article id by doing:

```
select ata.article_id
from articles_tags ata join
     tags t
     on ata.tag_id = t.id
where t.name in ('pencil', 'cats')
group by ata.article_id
having count(distinct t.name) = 2;
```

For your second question, you can use conditional aggregation.  Here is one method:

```
select ata.article_id
from articles_tags ata join
     tags t
     on ata.tag_id = t.id
where t.name in ('pencil', 'cats')
group by ata.article_id
having sum(t.name = 'pencil') > 0 and sum(t.name = 'cats') > 0;
```

You can join in `articles` to get additional columns if you need them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where is the whole `alias` column taking place there? Am I missing something?
Also, is your second query feasible for large amounts of searched tags?

Comment: @Imashcha . . . I don't understand the first question.  For the second, you need to try on your system.  The `join` and `group by` are not totally unreasonable operations.

Comment: The main part of the question was about the integration of the `alias` column as depicted in the table `tags`.